# PHP LDAP - Securing objects by AD Groups

Tags: php, security, ldap

Very New to PHP and LDAP, what I am trying to do in the simplest form is; We have a drop down box that has all of our different facilities in it. We want to only allow end users to see certain facilities, depending on an Active directory group they belong to.

So if doe, John, is in the "Houston office" group, he will only see the Houston Facility in the drop down.

If anyone could help out that would be huge.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: So far I have only been able to connect to our LDAP server and pull the group information. Like I said I am extremely new to both the PHP and LDAP. this is a small piece of a larger project and I wasn't sure if anyone knew of any similar cases or code that I could modify.

Comment: What do you mean by "group information"? Do you have a list of existing groups and people for each group? For a dropdown, you could try using something like [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). If you can, please post the code you have with hints as to where you're stuck. Then we can help you better.

Comment: I have AD groups created with the appropriate users in said groups. the code below looks like it just pulls all the OU information

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(30);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

// config
$ldapserver = 'LDAP.Server';
$ldapuser      = 'username'; 
$ldappass     = 'password';
$ldaptree    = "DC=company,DC=com";

// connect
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...<br /><br />";


        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(cn=*)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
        $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

        // SHOW ALL DATA
        echo '<h1>Dump all data</h1><pre>';
        print_r($data);   
        echo '</pre>';


        // iterate over array and print data for each entry
        echo '<h1>Show me the users</h1>';
        for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) {
            //echo "dn is: ". $data[$i]["dn"] ."<br />";
            echo "User: ". $data[$i]["cn"][0] ."<br />";
            if(isset($data[$i]["mail"][0])) {
                echo "Email: ". $data[$i]["mail"][0] ."<br /><br />";
            } else {
                echo "Email: None<br /><br />";
            }
        }
        // print number of entries found
        echo "Number of entries found: " . ldap_count_entries($ldapconn, $result);
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

// all done? clean up
ldap_close($ldapconn);
?>
```